# How to use Grid.js with data being updated every second

Tags: gridjs

```js
setInterval(() => {
  // lets update the config
  grid.updateConfig({
    server: {
      url: document.location.href + 'api.json/',
      then: data => data.map(obj => {
        return [obj.name, obj.value]
      }),
      handle: (res) => {
        // no matching records found
        if (res.status === 404) return { data: [] }
        if (res.ok) return res.json()
        throw Error('oh no :(')
      }
    }
  }).forceRender()
}, 2000)
```

This snippet make the work, but loading message and flicking/redraw all table are ruining UX.

Comment: Unfortunately `forceRender()` redraw all table. i don't think is possible to bypass that.

Comment: Sorry, to be precise is the `updateConfig()` method that redraw the table when it call